# play large size video in asp.net

Tags: html, asp.net

```
<object type="video/x-ms-wmv" data="CD-DigitalLibrary/VIDEO_TS/VIDEO_TS.VOB" width="720" height="585">
 <param name="src" value="CD-DigitalLibrary/VIDEO_TS/VIDEO_TS.VOB" />
 <param name="autostart" value="true" />
 <param name="controller" value="true" />
</object>
```

Above is working only for small size video. I need to play DVD video (it is a book). total file file is 610MB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because Object is buffering files in memory so it will freeze browser.

What you can do is:

1. Try VLC Web Plugin and try to stream video file to it.
2. Use Silverlight and stream video File from Server via URL.

We did same, our architecture was

Silverlight Player playing 3 GB's of file in frontend and it was pulling out stream from Server.
It takes time to buffer but it plays nicely with High speed internet.

Answer (score 0):

YouTube has a 2GB, 15 minute limit. Upload the video to YouTube and then copy the simple embed snippet. This works very well across many browsers and devices.

YouTube does the heavy lifting for you. The Youtube player is better than Silverlight, who wants to install Silverlight unless they have to and I am a Microsoft developer saying this. I have never used VLC Web Plugin but there is a very low probability that it could be easier to integrate than using YouTube to embed the content.